# Debian Lenny as Xen domU fails to boot

Tags: debian, xen, grub

here's the thing: I have Debian Lenny running Xen dom0, and I want to install another Debian Lenny as domU. I followed the guide at [Debian Wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/Xen) to the letter. Installation goes fine until Debian installer tries to install Grub, it fails with this error:

> Installation step failed
>
> An installation step failed. You can try to run the failing item
>   again from the menu, or skip it and choose something else. The
>   failing step is: Install the GRUB boot loader on a hard disk

If I ignore that, complete the installation and try to boot the machine, I get this:

> Loading, please wait...
>   Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done.
>   Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... FATAL: Error inserting fan (/lib/modules/2.6.26-2-686-bigmem/kernel/drivers/acpi/fan.ko): No such device
>   FATAL: Error inserting thermal (/lib/modules/2.6.26-2-686-bigmem/kernel/drivers> /acpi/thermal.ko): No such device
>   [    0.608267] blkfront: xvda1: barriers enabled
>   done.
>   Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
>   Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... done.
>   mount: cannot read /etc/fstab: No such file or directory
>   Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
>   done.
>   Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such > file or directory
>   done.
>   mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
>   mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
>   Target filesystem doesn't have /sbin/init.
>   No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.

My .conf file for Xen is pretty simple:

> kernel = '/vmlinuz'
>   ramdisk = '/initrd.img'
>   memory = 256
>   vif = ['bridge=xenbr0']
>   disk = [ 'file:/xen/root.img,hda1,w' ]

Any ideas where to start hunting for the problem? I'm pretty stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mount: cannot read /etc/fstab: No such file or directory
```

That's a pretty clear sign that your initramfs is borked. Probably because your install is borked.

How did you get past partitioning in debian-installer? Last time I did it (ummm... yesterday) I had to export something that I could partition, so your disk being hda1 is rather weird. Mine looks like:

```
disk = ['phy:/dev/GLaDOS/xen-portaltest,xvda,w']
```

its on a logical volume, not a file, but that shouldn't matter. Giving it `xvda1` or whatever didn't work; it wanted to partition that, which is fairly silly.

With `xvda`, I went ahead and partitioned that (into a xvda1 for `/boot` and an `xvda2` for a LVM physical volume, but you could certainly just use that for root). The installer then completed normally, and it works after dealing with the bootloader not executable error documented on [the Debian Wiki's Xen entry](http://wiki.debian.org/Xen).

Comment: Yep, initramfs was screwed up thanks to Debian. Marking this as correct, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How is the domU's fstab ? You may have erroneous lines that try to mount /sys under /root/sys

```
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
```